# When should we need to answer our question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked few question in Drupal exchange website and I have read several comments in other answer that we can answer our question.

So, I have some doubts what would be best scenario to answer our question.

- [node_load is not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91257/node-load-is-not-working)
- [Comment form is not working with ctools popup](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89351/comment-form-is-not-working-with-ctools-popup)
- [views arguments not working with context](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90253/views-arguments-not-working-with-context)

For the first Question, after reading suggestion from comments, I find out the solution for the question and for the second and third question, after R&D on  module, I find a solution for the question.

Should I need to post the solution as answer in both case or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no time frame for that, you can post your answers once you found the solution and also it will help the future visitors.

Suppose if someone suggested through comments, then you can include their name in your post like "as suggested by @user".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not want to credit the solution myself which is suggested by someone, so I want to know best way to manage this.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Just to add a bit: If comment gave solution directly, it might be nice to post `@` comment and ping the user who found solution, telling him to post it as an answer. First, it wil not "rob" him of the rep he has the moral right to get, and second, it will teach him to post answers as an answers, where they belong :) But if it was only a hint and solution is yours, or if he does not respond, post an answer yourself!

Comment: @Mołot, Yes, I want to give the rep which has the moral right to get it. I got hint(one of debug solution) in comments for question 1 but same time I found the solution of my problem.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola if someone only posted a *hint*, then by all means post a full answer yourself as soon as you know it :)

Comment: @Mołot, Thanks. I will do.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody else adds an answer, you are more than welcome to write one yourself. Keep in mind that answering your own question doesn't have different requirements: The answer still needs to be exhaustive as any answer given to other users' questions.

Comment: Sure, I will provide an answer which will be solution, not a dummy answer.